# Dot Product Calculation Link List Implementation

Tags: c++, vector, linked-list

I am trying to implement the a dot product calculation formula into the linked list implementation on my below code and I am having the below error: 
**request for member 'add_node' in 'B', which is of pointer type 'linked_list {aka node*}' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)**
How can I clear that and make working code? I don't want to use classes as well

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

struct node
{
    int data;
    int index;
    node *next;
};
typedef node* linked_list;

node *head = NULL;
node *tail = NULL;

void add_node(int i,int n)
{
    node *tmp = new node;
    tmp->index = i;
    tmp->data = n;
    tmp->next = NULL;
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        head = tmp;
        tail = tmp;
    }
    else
    {
        tail->next = tmp;
        tail = tail->next;
    }
}
void display(node *head)
{
    while(head!=0)
    {
        cout << head->index <<" ," << head->data << endl;
        display(head->next);
        break;
    }
}
int main()
{
    linked_list A;

    A.add_node(2,7);
    A.add_node(4,5);
    A.add_node(7,8);
    A.add_node(9,4);

    linked_list B;

    B.add_node(3,5);
    B.add_node(4,6);
    B.add_node(9,5);

    int product=0;

while(A!=0 && B!=0)
{
    if(A->index == B->index)
    {
        product = product + A->data * B->data;
        A=A->next;
        B=B->next;
    }
    else if(A->index < B->index)
    {
        A=A->next;
    }
    else
    {
        B=B->next;
    }
}
return product;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `node` struct has no member functions. Generally using typedef with a pointer leads to sadness down the road.

Comment: I have to say, these teachers can sure come up with novel ways to disguise the "linked list assignment" questions that come here 20 times a day.  Computing the dot product using a linked list? What's next?

Comment: You appear to be trying to run two distinct linked lists on a single global `head` and `tail`. This cannot work. I think you want to make a linked list class to split the two up.

Comment: When i used class, I am having issue on my While loop in main function   truct node
{
    int data;
    int index;
    node *next;
};
class linked_list
{
private:
    node *head,*tail;
public:
    linked_list()
    {
        head = NULL;
        tail = NULL;
    }
    void add_node(int i,int n){}
     void display(node *head){}

Comment: Rather than make a radical change to this question and invalidate the (Correct at the time) answer, you should have asked a new question. I'm going to revert your last edit. But the linked list is the right way to go and you're close. What you want to do is walk through the nodes in the linked list, not the linked list. You can get the head node from the list and do what you're doing in that `while` loop.

Comment: But the more ideologically correct way is add a `node * getNext(node * )` function to the linked list class to do the walking. That way you can sort of hide the linking machinery of the node from the caller. If you want he first node call with `nullptr` and have a case that returns `head`, otherwise return the given node's `next` pointer.

Comment: I have done those changes and it runs but does not provide a result

Comment: node *current_a = A.gethead();                                                                     while( current_a->data != 0 && current_b->data != 0)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160311/discussion-between-mwater07-and-user4581301).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node
{
    int data;
    int index;
    node *next;
};
class linked_list
{
private:
    node *head,*tail;
public:
    linked_list()
    {
        head = NULL;
        tail = NULL;
    }
    void add_node(int i,int n)
    {
        node *tmp = new node;
        tmp->index = i;
        tmp->data = n;
        tmp->next = NULL;

        if(head == NULL)
        {
            head = tmp;
            tail = tmp;
        }
        else
        {
            tail->next = tmp;
            tail = tail->next;
        }
    }
    node* gethead()
    {
        return head;
    }
};
     void display(node *head)
    {
        while(head!=0)
        {
            cout << head->index <<" ," << head->data << endl;
            display(head->next);
            break;
        }
    }
int main()
{
    linked_list A;

    A.add_node(2,7);
    A.add_node(4,5);
    A.add_node(7,8);
    A.add_node(9,4);

    linked_list B;

    B.add_node(3,5);
    B.add_node(4,6);
    B.add_node(9,5);

    display(A.gethead());
    display(B.gethead());

    int product=0;


    node *current_a = A.gethead();
    node *current_b = B.gethead();

    while(current_a != 0 && current_b!=0)
    {
        if(current_a->index == current_b->index)
        {
            product = product + current_a->data * current_b->data;
            current_a=current_a->next;
            current_b=current_b->next;
        }
        else if(current_a->index < current_b->index)
        {
            current_a=current_a->next;
        }
        else
        {
            current_b=current_b->next;
        }
    }
    cout<<"\nDot Product : "<< product<<endl;

    return 0;
}

    enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you what you need to know. `linked_list` is a pointer. You need to use the `->` operator, not the dot operator.

Additionally, your `node` struct does not contain a method called `add_node()`. In fact it doesn't contain any methods at all.

Comment: Except, `add_node` is not a member function.   The error is right, you need -> to dereference A, but once you do you'll have a new error.